# Form not showing in html - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I have a model that extends the User model in django, that model is a userprofile, I'll use to asociate aditional information to User model. I have the model, the form, the view, the url and the html, but the html is not showing the fiels, only shows the submit button.

here is the code:

models.py

```
class userProfile(models.Model):

    def url(self, filename):
        ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username, filename)
        return ruta

    user    =   models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    photo    =   models.ImageField(upload_to= url)
    telefono=   models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __srt__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class userProfileForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = userProfile
```

views.py

```
def perfil_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = userProfileForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            user = request
            perfil = userProfileForm(user = form.cleaned_data.get('user'),
                                    photo = form.cleaned_data['photo'],
                                    telefono = form.cleaned_data['telefono'],
                                    )
            perfil.save()
            ctx ={'form':form}
            return render_to_response('prueba.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
         else:
            ctx ={'form':form}
            return render_to_response('perfil.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
         form = userProfileForm()
    ctx ={'form':form}
    return render_to_response('prueba.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

prueba.html

```
{% extends "base2.html" %}
{% block title %}Prueba{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'melomanos.userProfile'
```

Comment: Your form needs to inherit from `forms.ModelForm`. You have a typo in the model `__srt__()` instead of `__str()__` (are you using Python 3? Otherwise you should use `__unicode__()`, I believe)

Comment: in your view, what's the use of `user = request` ?

Comment: Furthermore: your ModelForm should explicitly list the fields. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

Comment: Also: if you just want to add/enrich the attributes of a User and each user has __one__ profile only, then you should go for a one-to-one relationship: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Do you have all the necessary context processors in place? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Comment: Also: in your view, if the form is valid, creating another one is unnecessary. Use its cleaned_data `e.g. form.cleaned_data['fieldname']` or save it `form.save()`

Comment: In your template, the form must encode the data correctly (i.e. `multipart`), if you plan to upload a file/image. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really I'm very new in django. Can you say me what's the best way to extend the User model, I need to add a picture, city, and other fields, I tried everything but nothing works for me, I'm very novate. hehe

Comment: Thanks Pynchia, karthikr your comments was a great help for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
return render(request, 'prueba.html', ctx)
```

instead of

```
return render_to_response('prueba.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also, don't foreget to import render as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```